# Getting error "The container name is already in use by container "93b7..." (docker ps gives nothing)

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run `postgres` docker:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 -d postgres
```

I'm getting error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/some-postgres" is already in use by container "93b72872c89cf7497872b0bc0e98d5a91078666945e3ca39ce5cbb36c436b5af". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

I checked with:

```
sudo docker ps
```

And there is nothing:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

(Empty)

1. so, why I'm getting this error message ?
2. If the container name already exsits, How can I run it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this (shows all containers, includes stopped)

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

And then delete container

```
docker rm CONTAINER
```

Comment: Also, you can add option "--rm" in "docker run" command to automatically remove the container on exit.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

`docker ps -a` you will see existing container name and remove that using `docker rm some-postgres`. and run the docker run command again.